# Multiple permalink with and without category for same post

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, htaccess

It is a directory site with geodirectory plugin.

Site owner wants 2 URLs for every post. One with category and another without category.

For example:

1. `http://example.com/place/category-name/the-post-slug`

and

2. `http://example.com/place/the-post-slug` (or `http://example.com/place/878-the-post-slug`)

We can easily setup any one of them at a time. but we need 2 URL structure working at the same time.
I mean, by browsing both URLs, it needs to display the same post.

Is it possible?

Comment: Which one of these is the "canonical" URL? Are you intending to set a canonical meta tag to one or the other?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think, we should set canonical meta tag.
I warned already that, the multiple post appearance could be harmful for the SEO. 
But the site owner doesn't agree. Coz, they have an example site, where there are multiple content appearance.

The owner just interested to make post count double.
Any one of the urls, we can set "canonical".

Comment: Right, just curious regarding the clients (misconceived) motivation behind this.